# Ошыбка при запросе Ajax

Tags: ajax

при исполнения кода

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.delete_art_button').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://sait/pages/profil.php?login=Top",
            type: "POST",
            method: "POST",
            // dataType: "text",
            data: {ok: 'ok'},
            complete: function(data) {console.log(data);},
            error: function() {alert('-');},
            BeforeSend: function() {alert('-');}
        });
    });
</script>
```

у меня в консоле выводиться ошыбка - {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

а когда вывожу через алерт то виводит [object Object]

Comment: ошибки никакой нет. всё работает штатно

Comment: так у меня ничего не передаеться в пост